# How to create a dynamic library compatible with C ABI in Rust?

Tags: c, linux, rust

I'm new to Rust. For practice I'm trying to create a dynamic library compatible with C ABI in Rust.

My use case: I have an existing program written in C and it supports runtime plugins. Basically when the program initializes, it looks at the environment and loads the plugin, which is a dynamic library. The program assumes the metadata of the plugin (a struct of pointers to functions and a `const char*` identifier) is a global variable in the dynamic lib, if the lib is written in C. When the program needs certain functionality, it just calls the plugin by: `plugin->func(params)`. The plugin is what I'm trying to create here.

To clarify, the plugin would look something like this in C:

```c
// plugin.h
struct plugin_t {
  char *identifier;
  int (*foo)(int bar);
};

// plugin.c
int my_foo(int bar) {
  /* do something */
}

struct plugin_t plugin_impl = {
  .identifier = "net-plugin",
  .foo = my_foo,
};
```

I used bindgen to convert the plugin header file into a bindings.rs specification. `bindings.rs` is quite messy; complying with this specification would require a large amount of type conversion, both from and back to C. Besides, interfacing with C involves writing a lot of `unsafe` code, which contradicts with what makes Rust a great language to start with (memory safety).

Based on my experience and the great reputation Rust has in the community, I'm guessing I did it quite wrong. **My question is, what is the optimal way to create a dynamic library compatible with C ABI in Rust?** By optimal I mean to to decouple Rust code from C code as much as possible.

Comment: " Besides, interfacing with C involves writing a lot of unsafe code, which contradicts with what makes Rust a great language to start with (memory safety)." The C ABI is the C ABI, and completely unsafe (from Rust's point of view and definition of th term). Whether you use bindgen or create the API by hand, you'll have a non-trivial amount of unsafe at that edge, and the more details you expose over the interface the more unsafe you'll need.

Comment: And exposing struct contents and callbacks is a very high level of mess and madness, I'd suggest exposing static functions and opaque plugin state (that state can contain Rust-level structures / callbacks, but hidden from the C ABI).

Comment: @Masklinn thank you so much! Just one question, what exactly do you mean by "opaque plugin state"? Does it work like a handle, so that C programs only have abstracted references to the states, and would have to call specific APIs to manipulate them?

Comment: Yes, the API would return a `void*` (or maybe expose a struct by name to provide some type safety to the consumer of the API), and the caller would have to call into the API in order to query or or extract plugin state when and where necessary.